# Listar e contar resultados que se repetem dentro de um array

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
ID|  nome                      | Tipo
1 | Teste, João, Maria         | Indicação
2 | Teste, Maria, José         | Projeto de Lei
3 | Maria, José, João, Teste   | Indicação 
4 | Maria, João, José          | Denúncia
```

Precisava listar os tipos e contar a quantidade de cada um deles que tenha determinado nome, ex:

**Nome: Teste**

- Indicação (2)
- Projeto de Lei (1)
- Denúncia (0)

Montei o código abaixo mas não funcionou:

```
SELECT   tipo,
         COUNT(tipo) AS Qtd
FROM  pessoas
WHERE FIND_IN_SET ("teste", nome)
ORDER BY COUNT(tipo) DESC
```

Veja o exemplo na prática:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b41e8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se a pergunta como entendi é a resposta como espera, o que fiz baseado na compreensão foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Assim:**

```
SELECT *,COUNT(tipo) AS Qtd
FROM pessoas
WHERE FIND_IN_SET ("teste", nome)
GROUP BY tipo
```

Comment: É isso sim, mas e se eu quisesse listar também os tipos que não tem nenhuma quantidade?

Comment: Você muda a condição do seu WHERE, pois você especificou qual a condição dos resultados, certo?

Comment: Confere, resultando quando não há nulo, considerando vazio http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d02feb2/1

Comment: Acho que vou conseguir adaptar para o que eu preciso. Obrigado pela ajuda Eliseu